# MSBuild: Include a custom resource file as embedded resource

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I am dynamically generating a resource-file at build time with MSBuild, but in order to be able to read from this resource file at run-time, I need it to be an embedded resource.

I have looked everywhere at how to mark a file in a `.csproj` as embedded resource, I have even tried this to no avail.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="Infrastructure\Content\Store\content_store_en.json" />
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Infrastructure\Content\Store\content_store_en.json">
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Comment: Please mark it as answered if it helped you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <CreateItem Include="Infrastructure\**\*.json">
        <Output ItemName="EmbeddedResource" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>
</Target>
```

Source: http://ayende.com/blog/4446/how-to-setup-dynamic-groups-in-msbuild-without-visual-studio-ruining-them

I changed the CreateItem attribute so it will reflect your question.

I hope it helps...