# How to mark files of a folder as embedded resource with wildcards with the new project format?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

My scenario is simple.
I have test project where i want all files within a folder to be marked as embedded resource by default. To prevent someone from doing mistakes here i want this to be automatic through wildcards

I looked at this question, which looked very promising.
[MSBuild: Include a custom resource file as embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559371/msbuild-include-a-custom-resource-file-as-embedded-resource)

However that does not seem to work with the new csproj format. Does anyone know what i should be doing different for it to work with the new format?

My current code is this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Shouldly" Version="3.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="3.2.1" />
    </ItemGroup>


    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <CreateItem Include="TestContent\*.cs">
            <Output ItemName="EmbeddedResource" TaskParameter="Include" />
        </CreateItem>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this script:

```
  <Target Name="MyCustomStep" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
        <CreateItem Include="TestContent\*.cs">
            <Output ItemName="EmbeddedResource" TaskParameter="Include" />
        </CreateItem>
  </Target>
```

There exists difference between the BeforeBuild Target in old and new csproj format. (Or maybe the difference between .net core and .net framewrok, not sure about this point)

**Some discoveries when I set the [msbuild verbosity](https://dailydotnettips.com/back-to-basic-displaying-detailed-output-of-msbuild-in-visual-studio-output-window/) to Detailed:**

1.For projects that target `.net framework` using the old csproj format:
[image]

The `BeforeBuild` target will exactly execute the `CreateItem` Task. So it works for old-format project files.

2.For projects that target `.net core` using new sdk format:

[image]

The `BeforeBuild` target seems not to execute the task as what we expected.

After defining the `Custom target` which executes before the `BeforeBuild` target, it works in my machine:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. Yes. This version works - Buildwise at least. VS does not display the build action as EmbeddedResource however. What do you reckon is the best place to report that bug? github/msbuild or VS report?

Comment: For this issue, github/msbuild can be more suitable.  Update the answer with more details:)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and the effort you put in :)